# Advanced Custom Fields - category image

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get an image for I previously assigned to a category using ACF.

here's what I'm doing:

```
$category_image = the_field('cat_small', $linkedcat);
```

where $linkedcat is something like category_280

When I echo $category_image, i see an array, like so:

```
261, , catsmall, , , http://localhost/current/dpf/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/catsmall.jpg, Array
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Many thx!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever in doubt, consult the documentation and nice plugins like ACF are very well documented.

It depends on how you set the image field, but from this page [*Field Types -> Image*](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/image/), looks like you set you field to return an object.

Instead of using `the_field`, which *prints* the value, you need [**`get_field`**](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/):

```
$category_image = get_field('cat_small', $linkedcat);
```

And then:

```
$image = $category_image['url'];
```

Or, if available:

```
$thumb = $category_image['sizes']['thumbnail'];
```

Also, instead of `echo`, use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to debug arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign image on your category or taxonomy, I suggest [Categories Image Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/), it will allow you to add image with category or taxonomy.

Use `<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>` to get the url and put it in any img tag in (category or taxonomy) template.